# How to remove duplication after selecting from two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to select from two table but I get false duplication within the result I want

Table A contains:

```
code name value1
   1    a    a11
   2    b    b21
```

Table B contains:

```
code name value2
   1    a    a12
   2    b    b22
```

Expected result:

```
code name value1 value2
   1    a    a11    a12
   2    b    b21    b22
```

The query I made

```
 select   a.code , a.name , a.value1 , b.value2  from A a , B b where a.code = b.code ;
```

The result I got

```
code name value1 value2
   1    a    a11    a12
   2    b    a11    a12
   1    a    b21    b22
   2    b    b21    b22
```

Comment: You should get the result as expected..

Comment: i didn't get it the result i got is as shown

Comment: Add (3,a,a33) to one of the tables, and then adjust the expected result.

Comment: The query you posted with the sample data you posted produces your expected output. So there's something in your set-up which you haven't included in your question. Most likely explanation is that `code` is not the primary of `A` and/or `B' and so contains duplicates which lead to a cross join. Clearly we can't resolve your issue without a reproducible test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add name to key:

```
select   a.code , a.name , a.value1 , b.value2  
from A a , B b 
where a.code = b.code 
and a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it

Comment: sure i just had a timing